# Labels of list items CAPITALIZED + bold style

Tags: formatting, lists, bold, capitalization, description

Is there a possibility to make the labels of `description` list items always appear CAPITALIZED and **bold**?

Comment: Would you be able to produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows your current usage?

Comment: The `itemize` environment uses bullets as labels by default. So, what exactly do want to have bold? Do you want bigger bullets?

Comment: I think you're actually describing an `enumerate` environment- if so, please make the edit to your question. You can use the `enumitem` package with `\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\Alph*,font=\bf}` in your pre-amble.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you mention capitalizing `itemize`d labels, I'm assuming you're using

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item[<label>] ...
  \item[<label>] ...
  ...
\end{itemize}
```

If this is the case, you could just use the `description` environment, and modify `\descriptionlabel` - the macro that makes the `description` environment labels:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
  \normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}% Make description environment label bold/CAPITALIZED
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text
\begin{description}
  \item[one] Here is some text
  \item[two] Here is some more text
  \item[three] Here is the final item
\end{description}
Here is some more text
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Sorry I used your example. I was to lazy ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I recommend the package `enumitem` which allows a lot of settings.

In your case it is simple using the option `font`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text
\begin{description}[font=\bfseries\MakeUppercase]
  \item[one] Here is some text
  \item[two] Here is some more text
  \item[three] Here is the final item
\end{description}
Here is some more text
\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if I understood your inquiry fully, but it seems to me that you're looking to create an **enumerated** list in which the items are not numbered with digits (1, 2, 3, ...) but with the numbers' English language names, uppercased and boldfaced. Actually, you mention an *itemized* list, but itemized lists are are not "numbered"; instead, list items are usually "labeled" with symbols such as bullet points, en-dashes, and little upside-down triangles.

If my interpretation is correct, here's an MWE (minimum working example) that uses the `enumitem` and `moreenum` packages to achieve your objective. (If you don't want the number strings to be terminated by a period, just leave off the "." after "\NWORDS*".)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,moreenum}
\setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries,label=\NWORDS*.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Here we go.
\item Where are we going?
\item I think we're lost.
\item I wonna go home.
\item Home at last.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The below method is good if you have one or two description lists.

```
\begin{description}[font=\bfseries\MakeUppercase]
  \item[Random] stuff
  \item[Some more Random] Stuff
  \item[Here again] Some more random stuff
\end{description}
```

Copying `[font=\bfseries\MakeUppercase]` to every description list does the job.

However, when you have lot of documents and you want to make changes to *all* the description lists, below method saves a world of pain.

Use the package `enumitem`. Below is an **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{VGray}{HTML}{575759}

%%%%%description Level 1%%%%%
\setlist[description,1]{font=\normalfont\scshape\color{VRed}}    

%%%%%description Level 2%%%%%
\setlist[description,2]{font=\normalfont\scshape\color{blue}}

%%%%%description Level 3%%%%%
\setlist[description,3]{font=\normalfont\scshape\color{cyan}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
        \item[random] This is description \emph{Level 1}
        \begin{description}
            \item[some more] This is description \emph{Level 2}
            \begin{description}
                \item[even more] This is description \emph{Level 3}
            \end{description}
        \end{description}
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]