# Making text in {braces} of an \item appear bold

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize

Is it possible to redefine `\item` to have the text in braces appear bold?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item{Paper}: a white substance used for writing symbols.
  \item{Pencil}: a tool for writing symbols on a paper
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the following output:

> - **Paper**: a white substance used for writing symbols
> - **Pencil**: a tool for writing symbols on a paper

I intend to place this in a template. Note that this is not used a glossary; rather, it is used for short overview of a variety of items that may, were the text a bit more extended, deserve a subsection, except each item is too short to deserve a subsection.

Comment: Use `\begin{description}…\end{description}` and put it in brackets `\item[Paper]: …`.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks! I found that out immediately after posting the question. The "Related" section turned out to have a useful q&a listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to using a `{}` and also want the bullets from `itemize`d lists you could use `\MyItem` instead as defined below:

[image]

Alternatively you could define a customized `MyItemize` environment in which you redefine `\item` to do this, but I would recommend using `\MyItem` instead.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\MyItem}[1]{\item \textbf{#1}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \MyItem{Paper}: a white substance used for writing symbols.
  \MyItem{Pencil}: a tool for writing symbols on a paper
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's a bit closer to what I originally envisioned -- although I'll use `description` as it seems to have nicer formatting for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, StackExchange's "Related" section that appeared after I posted the question!

I should actually be [using the `description` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41525/labels-of-list-items-capitalized-bold-style?rq=1) and brackets instead of braces. Then I'll get the exact behavior I want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Paper] a white substance used for writing symbols.
  \item[Pencil] a tool for writing symbols on a paper
\end{description}

\end{document}
```